# initWithNibName method in storyboard

Tags: xcode, facebook, storyboard

I am following Facebook's tutorial to post to a user's wall: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/publish-to-feed-ios-sdk/
and although it is made with a .xib project in mind, I have been able to do everything just fine with my storyboard project so far. However, I have come to the point where I need to put some code into the initWithNibName:bundle: method, but I cannot do this because I am using storyboard. And, since it's hard to tell when exactly the method would be called, I can't just write a method named initWithNibName:bundle: and call it from some other method. If anyone has any idea of how to solve my issue, please say so. Thanks.

Comment: I created a simple project in GitHub as an example using the FB SDK + iOS 6 and Storyboards. The app can post in the timeline: [FB SDK + Storyboards with Publish to Feed](https://github.com/Belzebul/fb-sdk-storyboards) Hopefully this may be useful.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I just ran into this problem myself. Storyboards appear to not use `initWithNibName:bundle:`, but either `initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder` or `initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style`.

The default implementations of the two methods look like:

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}
```

I've yet to use the initWithStyle version myself, but I'd imagine it's called for a UITableViewController. If in doubt, you could simply add both methods to the file, along with an NSLog() call that prints the method's name (or any other unique string). You can then run it in the simulator to see which is called, and delete the other.

I'd strongly recommend against calling `initWithNibName:bundle:` yourself from any of the other `init` methods. Better to just move the code to the correct method.

Comment: some of the best advice I have ever seen

Comment: If storyboard is not using initWithNib - why is it created by default when adding a new class using xcode 4.5 and storyboard?

Comment: @Odelya I'm not sure what the deal is with that (it's definitely quite confusing). Seems like an oversight at the very least to leave them out of the default template (especially since using Storyboards is encouraged). I've not found any official explanation for that, although Apple's documentation for `initWithNibName:bundle:` says that the `initWithCoder:` method is used instead when dealing with Storyboards. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/initWithNibName:bundle:

Comment: still getting this kind of confusing thing in iOS7 and Xcode5.

Comment: regarding "why is it created" -- i.e. in the example code XCode spits out.  Just forget about it - basically MOST of the example code XCode spits out, when you create something, is highly wrong. It means, nothing, just ignore it.  As Kitsune says, it's an oversight by Apple (but something the "oversight" very often, heh.)

Comment: Well in Xcode 6.1 there is no more auto-generated code at all. I guess that's better than confusing people with wrong code.