# UITableview not showing content/ empty cells

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm still learning iOS and this is my first major project, so go easy on me. I'm trying to make a gesture-driven task list. I still have a lot of work to do, but I hope you guys can help me get this working. I'm certain I set the delegate and data source properly, but it's still not showing up...anyway, here's my ViewController.m file.

Thank you in advance!!

```
#import "AGViewController.h"
#import "AGTaskObject.h"
#import "AGTableViewCell.h"

//#import "AGSettingsViewController.h"


@interface AGViewController ()

@end

@implementation AGViewController {

    NSMutableArray *taskItems;
}

-(id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self)
    {
        //Initializing the Array
        taskItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

        [taskItems addObject:[AGTaskObject toDoItemWithText:@"Tap the + to add a Task"]];
        [taskItems addObject:[AGTaskObject toDoItemWithText:@"Tap the Gear Button to check out settings"]];
        [taskItems addObject:[AGTaskObject toDoItemWithText:@"Swipe Right to check off a task"]];
        [taskItems addObject:[AGTaskObject toDoItemWithText:@"Swipe Left to Delete a Task"]];
        [taskItems addObject:[AGTaskObject toDoItemWithText:@"I <3 Bacon"]];
    }
        return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //Table View Delegates
    self.tableView.delegate = self;
    self.tableView.dataSource = self;

    //set the initial background image
    self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    self.backgroundImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"blue.png"];
    [self.tableView registerClass:[AGTableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"cell"];

    //Get rid of empty cells at bottom of tableview
//    self.tableView.tableFooterView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];

    // Long Press Gesture to rearrange cells
    UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPress = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(longPressGestureRecognized:)];
    [self.tableView addGestureRecognizer:longPress];

//    // Tap Gesture to add a new cell
//    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(<#selector#>)];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Button Press (IB)Actions

- (IBAction)settingsButtonPressed:(UIButton *)sender
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"toSettingsViewController" sender:nil];
}

- (IBAction)addTaskButtonPressed:(UIButton *)sender
{  
}

#pragma mark - UITableView Configuration

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [taskItems count];
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *cellIdentifier = @"cell";
    //re-Use  or create a tableview cell
    AGTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier
                                                            forIndexPath:indexPath];
/*    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[AGTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
  */

    //Make the cells clear to show the background image
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    //default font color will be white
    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    //Set the task for each cell in the tableview
    AGTaskObject *item = taskItems[indexPath.row];
    //set the text
    cell.delegate = self;
    cell.taskObject = item;

    // Recall final cell
    return cell;
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    cell.backgroundColor = [self colorForIndex:indexPath.row];
}

#pragma mark - TableItem Delete

-(void)toDoItemDeleted:(id)taskobject {
    // use the UITableView to animate the removal of this row
    NSUInteger index = [taskItems indexOfObject:taskobject];
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
    [taskItems removeObject:taskobject];
    [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:index inSection:0]]
                          withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    [self.tableView endUpdates];
}
```

Comment: Did you connect IBOutlet tableView object to xib?

Comment: Martin H does have a point there. And you're also not setting the text in cells. `cell.textLabel.text = ...;` Since your starting out with iOS you might want to add a few `NSLog(@"i'm here");` lines (with more appropriate content) so you would see better what is going on with the code - [example of using NSLog](http://pragmaticcoding.com/index.php/nslog-from-beginning-to-advanced/)

Comment: check also http://stackoverflow.com/a/11990455/653513

Comment: Thanks guys... this helps a lot! My cell.textLabel.text is set. Also, moving the array into ViewDidLoad helped. Still a few more bugs, but I got a display with is way more helpful. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Storyboards don't use initWithNibName (even though Xcode creates it pointlessly) so your array is empty. Try moving it to viewDidLoad